# Windows 7 & Windows 8 VPN Client for Netgear FVS318

Tags: windows, vpn, netgear

The Netgear FVS318 Reference Guide (ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/FVS318v11_Refguide.pdf) states:

> The PC must have a VPN client program that supports IPSec. NETGEAR recommends and supports the SafeNet SoftRemote (or Soft-PK) Secure VPN Client for Windows, Version 5 or later. The SafeNet VPN Client can be purchased from SafeNet at http://www.safenet-inc.com.

However, I would greatly prefer to use the standard Windows client software rather than installing 3rd party VPN clients (which from past experience are often not upgraded for new Windows versions). I can't even find the SafeNet VPN Client at this URL!

Is it possible to configure the FVS318 so that the the built-in VPN client in Windows 7 and later can connect to it?